# "Login To Google account website via browser by .Net application"

Tags: selenium, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, google-cloud-platform, actions-on-google

I would like to login to Google Account automatically using tools similar to Selenium (Google seems to be blocking any automation tool).
Our  current application is .Net based, using selenium but as Google is blocking selenium access, we would consider any other alternatives (even if not .Net based) as long as we can trigger this workflow from an application call (Exe).

I was thinking about getting some kind of token using REST API, then using the token in url (for example: google.com/?logmeinPlease=[TOKEN]).

I've searched through web, but I couldn't find any solutions to my issue. Your help will be gladly appreciated, Thank you, Yulia

Answer (score 0):

This is not good practice in selenium .
For multiple reasons, logging into sites like Gmail and Facebook using WebDriver is not recommended. Aside from being against the usage terms for these sites (where you risk having the account shut down), it is slow and unreliable.

The ideal practice is to use the APIs that email providers offer, or in the case of Facebook the developer tools service which exposes an API for creating test accounts, friends and so forth. Although using an API might seem like a bit of extra hard work, you will be paid back in speed, reliability, and stability. The API is also unlikely to change, whereas webpages and HTML locators change often and require you to update your test framework.

Logging in to third party sites using WebDriver at any point of your test increases the risk of your test failing because it makes your test longer. A general rule of thumb is that longer tests are more fragile and unreliable.

WebDriver implementations that are W3C conformant also annotate the navigator object with a WebDriver property so that Denial of Service attacks can be mitigated.

Please check seleniumHQ website for more details .I f you want to get practice in selenium  [Here free sites](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&ved=2ahUKEwjo5bW8yMLsAhXCSH0KHSz9AtgQFjABegQIBhAC&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.techbeamers.com%2Fwebsites-to-practice-selenium-webdriver-online%2F&usg=AOvVaw0o19S7oZpgCEEkOsGghlHR) use these

Comment: Thank you for the response. Our application have to perform the login automatically without human interaction, and the result of the login should be browser connected with the requested google account. I tried to implement it via API but it's not possible. Do you know any other way to do it?